# Rails 4: .save does not update updated_at for existing records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I always thought `.save` and `.save!` would update the `updated_at` column of existing records. Is this not true? If so, then do I need to create a before_save filter to update it everytime I save?

Today is June 18th:

```
    Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.1)
    irb(main):001:0>  o = Order.last
      Order Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `orders`.* FROM `orders`   ORDER BY `orders`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
    => #<Order id: 24, user_id: 1, order_date: nil, total_cents: 0, total_currency: "USD", shipping_cents: 0, shipping_currency: "USD", tax_cents: 0, tax_currency: "USD", subtotal_cents: 0, subtotal_currency: "USD", created_at: "2014-06-13 21:24:38", updated_at: "2014-06-13 21:24:38", status: "Incomplete", coupon_id: nil>
    irb(main):002:0> o.save!
       (0.4ms)  BEGIN
       (0.3ms)  COMMIT
    => true
    irb(main):003:0> o.updated_at
    => Fri, 13 Jun 2014 21:24:38 UTC +00:00
    irb(main):004:0> o.reload
      Order Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `orders`.* FROM `orders`  WHERE `orders`.`id` = 24 LIMIT 1
    => #<Order id: 24, user_id: 1, order_date: nil, total_cents: 0, total_currency: "USD", shipping_cents: 0, shipping_currency: "USD", tax_cents: 0, tax_currency: "USD", subtotal_cents: 0, subtotal_currency: "USD", created_at: "2014-06-13 21:24:38", updated_at: "2014-06-13 21:24:38", status: "Incomplete", coupon_id: nil>
    irb(main):005:0> o.updated_at
    => Fri, 13 Jun 2014 21:24:38 UTC +00:00
```

The reason I care about this is because I am wrapping the internals of a function with `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` so I want to test that they are not updated when something goes wrong:

Rspec test (that passes all the time when it's not supposed to, since updated_at isn't being changed regardless of success or failure):

```
  it "rollsback the transaction" do
    ...
    order.stub(:save!).and_raise(StandardError)
    expect { payment_info.save }.not_to change { [billing_address.updated_at, 
                                                  shipping_address.updated_at,
                                                  order.user.updated_at,
                                                  order.updated_at] }
  end
```

And my method:

```
def process_billing_info!
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    billing_address.save!
    shipping_address.save!
    user.save!
    order.update_all_fees!
  end
rescue Exception => e
  false
end
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As you can see in your log, there is no `UPDATE` SQL query that is executed. Rails is not updating your record at all. This is because `.save` actually **saves the record only if changes were made**.

There is the method `.touch` ([Documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/touch)) that you can call in order to update the `updated_at` field without having to do changes to your record:

```
1.9.3p489 :005 > Intervention.first.touch
  Intervention Load (12.9ms)  SELECT "interventions".* FROM "interventions" LIMIT 1
  SQL (20.5ms)  UPDATE "interventions" SET "updated_at" = '2014-06-18 16:34:03.924648' WHERE "interventions"."id" = 1
 => true
```

Here we see the `UPDATE` SQL query.

Comment: Good point. It was because I wasn't changing `order` in any way, so `updated_at` didn't change

Comment: Thanks, I was using update_columns in my after_save filter in order to avoid an infinite loop. This was not updating the updated_at field. So I explicitly updated the field.

Comment: @SimmiBadhan in theory, you should not us `update_columns` because it skips the callbacks. You should use the `before_save` and assign the desired attribute to the (computed) value, and then let Rails save the record. The `before_save` is reached once the validations are passed. Which means your record is already `.valid?` when executing this code.

Comment: @MrYoshiji I tried using before_save filter too. But that leads to an infinite loop when the record gets saved. The solution to my problem was to use  update_columns only as I didn't need callbacks and I just wanted to update a hash field with some info.

Answer (score 6):

In companion with @MrYoshiji's answer, here's another way to use `.touch`:

```
if o.save!
  o.touch unless o.changed?
end
```

Comment: Was having an issue where I needed to update the record's timestamp everytime an update action was run. a modified version of this answer is what I needed:
`if record.update(params)
  record.touch unless record.changed?
end`